# Zend Framework 2 Table Gateway USE INDEX

Tags: php, zend-framework2, tablegateway

I'm using the ZF2 table gateway for a database select with following join:

```
$select->join('feedback'
    , new Expression('feedback_id = feedbackcar_feedback_id')
    , ['provider_foreign_id' => 'feedback_action_provider_foreign_id']
    , Select::JOIN_INNER);
```

How can I add `"USE INDEX (idx_actionforeignid_productid_providerrecommend)"`?

Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

`Zend\Db\Sql\Select` is not flexible enough to avail such a feat. You will be better off with a manually written sql query.